# I have TNS error when select from view

Tags: oracle

I have a view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dte_blmb_trd_acct_vw AS
    SELECT
        rtrim(strbk_book_name) bb_trd_acct,
        rtrim(strbk_description) description,
        trading_acct ici_trd_acct
    FROM
        spider.sp_struct_books@spdn b1,
        dte_trading_acct
    WHERE
        substr(rtrim(strbk_book_name),1,2) = ltrim(rtrim(fits_trading_acct) )
        AND   strbk_last_update_date = (
            SELECT
                MAX(strbk_last_update_date)
            FROM
                spider.sp_struct_books@spdn b2
            WHERE
                b2.strbk_book_number = b1.strbk_book_number
        );
```

separate it works, but when I select from `dte_blmb_trd_acct_vw`
it gives `TNS` error

Comment: please issue `tnsping spdn` from your OS

Comment: Here are my thoughts. 1) include your entire error text. 2) if it works sometimes, then show what works 3) if you get an error when you create the view, then say so 4) if you get an error when you use the view, then say so and include the error.

Comment: What is the definition of the spdn dblink, it is owned by you, public, ...?